# Убрать из строки определенное количество символов

Tags: php, html, css

Есть строка

```
241,284,234,248
```

Тут через запятую указаны id постов. Нужно убрать несколько первых id. Сколько именно не известно - будем считать n количество нужно убрать.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Можно разбить на массив и удалить что нужно и заджойнить

Comment: `implode(',', @array_splice( explode(',', "241,284,234,248"), 1, 3 ));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '241,284,234,248';
$arr = explode(",",$string);
$n = 2;
$new_arr = array_slice($arr,$n);
$new_arr = implode(",",$new_arr);
print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуемся третьим аргументом `explode`, который определяет сколько элементов хочется получить в итоге. Если надо удалить два первых элемента, значит определим параметр как 3 и возьмем последний элемент из результатов `explode`:

```
$string = '241,284,234,248';
$n = 2;
$parts = explode(',', $string, $n + 1);
print_r(array_pop($parts));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = '241,284,234,248';

const array = string.split(',');

// удалить первые два c 0 два штуки
console.log(array.splice(0,2));
// заджойнить
console.log(array.splice(0,2).join(','));
```

Comment: Вроде тега js тут нет.

Comment: От блин не внимателен ) Да не заметил что тут php

Comment: Ну тоже норм, будет как вариант)